# Update com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl

Tags: java, sql

I'm using the Java package `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl`. Can you tell me is there a new Java package in Java 7 which I can use instead of this package?

Comment: That is not a package, that is a class. It is completely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I get the message com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release. How I can solve this?

Comment: Don't use it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [javax.sql.*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/package-summary.html#package_description) package directly. Read the javadoc, and consider implementations of [CachedRowSet here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html)